# ValueError: Expected input batch_size (256) to match target batch_size (16).のエラー

Tags: python, 深層学習, pytorch

DeepLearningのコード（WideResNet）を実装しようと思い、自作のデータセットによる学習を試みているのですが、損失の計算時にエラーが出ます。
実装をメインとしており、自作データで学習をすることが目標で、アルゴリズムそのものの理解ができておらず、至らぬ点がありますが、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。
コメントアウトなどを削除したため、エラー文のlineと実際のエラー箇所が異なっています。

'''エラー文'''

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_mydata.py", line 350, in <module>
    main()
  File "train_mydata.py", line 196, in main
    train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, epoch)
  File "train_mydata.py", line 227, in train
    loss = criterion(output, target)
  File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 1163, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2996, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (256) to match target batch_size (16).
```

'''コードとエラー箇所'''

```
import argparse
import os
import shutil
import time
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn.parallel
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import torch.optim
import torch.utils.data
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torch.autograd import Variable

from wideresnet import WideResNet

# used for logging to TensorBoard
from tensorboard_logger import configure, log_value
 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch WideResNet Training')
parser.add_argument('--dataset', default='mydata', type=str,
                    help='dataset (cifar10 [default] or cifar100)')
parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=200, type=int,
                    help='number of total epochs to run')
parser.add_argument('--start-epoch', default=0, type=int,
                    help='manual epoch number (useful on restarts)')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size', default=16, type=int,
                    help='mini-batch size (default: 128)')
parser.add_argument('--lr', '--learning-rate', default=0.1, type=float,
                    help='initial learning rate')
parser.add_argument('--momentum', default=0.9, type=float, help='momentum')
parser.add_argument('--nesterov', default=True, type=bool, help='nesterov momentum')
parser.add_argument('--weight-decay', '--wd', default=5e-4, type=float,
                    help='weight decay (default: 5e-4)')
parser.add_argument('--print-freq', '-p', default=10, type=int,
                    help='print frequency (default: 10)')
parser.add_argument('--layers', default=28, type=int,
                    help='total number of layers (default: 28)')
parser.add_argument('--widen-factor', default=10, type=int,
                    help='widen factor (default: 10)')
parser.add_argument('--droprate', default=0, type=float,
                    help='dropout probability (default: 0.0)')
parser.add_argument('--no-augment', dest='augment', action='store_false',
                    help='whether to use standard augmentation (default: True)')
parser.add_argument('--resume', default='', type=str,
                    help='path to latest checkpoint (default: none)')
parser.add_argument('--name', default='WideResNet-28-10', type=str,
                    help='name of experiment')
parser.add_argument('--tensorboard',
                    help='Log progress to TensorBoard', action='store_true')
parser.set_defaults(augment=True)

best_prec1 = 0

def main():
    global args, best_prec1
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.tensorboard: configure("runs/%s"%(args.name))

    # Data loading code

    normal_mean = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    normal_std = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

    if args.augment:
        transform_train = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.RandomCrop(size=150,
                              padding=int(150*0.125),
                              padding_mode='reflect'),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=normal_mean,
                             std=normal_std)
    ])

    transform_test = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=normal_mean,
                             std=normal_std)
    ])

 
    train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(
                        root = "./mydata/500mydata",
                        transform = transform_train
                        )
    test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(
                        root = "./mydata/test1",
                        transform = transform_test
                        )
        
    kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': False}

    
    
    train_loader = DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=args.batch_size,
        sampler=RandomSampler(train_dataset),
        num_workers=1,
        drop_last=True)

    test_loader = DataLoader(
        test_dataset,
        batch_size=args.batch_size,
        sampler=SequentialSampler(test_dataset),
        num_workers=1)

    # create model
    model = WideResNet(args.layers,args.widen_factor, dropRate=args.droprate)

    # get the number of model parameters
    print('Number of model parameters: {}'.format(
        sum([p.data.nelement() for p in model.parameters()])))

    # for training on multiple GPUs.
    # Use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 to specify which GPUs to use
    # model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()
    model = model.cuda()

    # optionally resume from a checkpoint
    if args.resume:
        if os.path.isfile(args.resume):
            print("=> loading checkpoint '{}'".format(args.resume))
            checkpoint = torch.load(args.resume)
            args.start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
            best_prec1 = checkpoint['best_prec1']
            model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
            print("=> loaded checkpoint '{}' (epoch {})"
                  .format(args.resume, checkpoint['epoch']))
        else:
            print("=> no checkpoint found at '{}'".format(args.resume))

    cudnn.benchmark = True

    # define loss function (criterion) and optimizer
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().cuda()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), args.lr,
                                momentum=args.momentum, nesterov = args.nesterov,
                                weight_decay=args.weight_decay)

    # cosine learning rate
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, len(train_loader)*args.epochs)

    for epoch in range(args.start_epoch, args.epochs):
        # train for one epoch
        train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, epoch)

        # evaluate on validation set
        prec1 = validate(test_loader, model, criterion, epoch)

        # remember best prec@1 and save checkpoint
        is_best = prec1 > best_prec1
        best_prec1 = max(prec1, best_prec1)
        save_checkpoint({
            'epoch': epoch + 1,
            'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'best_prec1': best_prec1,
        }, is_best)
    print('Best accuracy: ', best_prec1)

def train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, epoch):
    """Train for one epoch on the training set"""
    batch_time = AverageMeter()
    losses = AverageMeter()
    top1 = AverageMeter()

    # switch to train mode
    model.train()

    end = time.time()
    for i, (input, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        target = target.cuda(non_blocking=True)
        input = input.cuda(non_blocking=True)

        # compute output
        output = model(input)
        loss = criterion(output, target)

        # measure accuracy and record loss
        prec1 = accuracy(output.data, target, topk=(1,))[0]
        losses.update(loss.data.item(), input.size(0))
        top1.update(prec1.item(), input.size(0))

        # compute gradient and do SGD step
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

        # measure elapsed time
        batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
        end = time.time()

        if i % args.print_freq == 0:
            print('Epoch: [{0}][{1}/{2}]\t'
                  'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Loss {loss.val:.4f} ({loss.avg:.4f})\t'
                  'Prec@1 {top1.val:.3f} ({top1.avg:.3f})'.format(
                      epoch, i, len(train_loader), batch_time=batch_time,
                      loss=losses, top1=top1))
    # log to TensorBoard
    if args.tensorboard:
        log_value('train_loss', losses.avg, epoch)
        log_value('train_acc', top1.avg, epoch)

def validate(test_loader, model, criterion, epoch):
    """Perform validation on the validation set"""
    batch_time = AverageMeter()
    losses = AverageMeter()
    top1 = AverageMeter()

    # switch to evaluate mode
    model.eval()

    end = time.time()
    for i, (input, target) in enumerate(test_loader):
        target = target.cuda(non_blocking=True)
        input = input.cuda(non_blocking=True)

        # compute output
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model(input)
        loss = criterion(output, target)

        # measure accuracy and record loss
        prec1 = accuracy(output.data, target, topk=(1,))[0]
        losses.update(loss.data.item(), input.size(0))
        top1.update(prec1.item(), input.size(0))

        # measure elapsed time
        batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
        end = time.time()

        if i % args.print_freq == 0:
            print('Test: [{0}/{1}]\t'
                  'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Loss {loss.val:.4f} ({loss.avg:.4f})\t'
                  'Prec@1 {top1.val:.3f} ({top1.avg:.3f})'.format(
                      i, len(test_loader), batch_time=batch_time, loss=losses,
                      top1=top1))

    print(' * Prec@1 {top1.avg:.3f}'.format(top1=top1))
    # log to TensorBoard
    if args.tensorboard:
        log_value('test_loss', losses.avg, epoch)
        log_value('test_acc', top1.avg, epoch)
    return top1.avg


def save_checkpoint(state, is_best, filename='checkpoint.pth.tar'):
    """Saves checkpoint to disk"""
    directory = "runs/%s/"%(args.name)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    filename = directory + filename
    torch.save(state, filename)
    if is_best:
        shutil.copyfile(filename, 'runs/%s/'%(args.name) + 'model_best.pth.tar')

class AverageMeter(object):
    """Computes and stores the average and current value"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count

def accuracy(output, target, topk=(1,)):
    """Computes the precision@k for the specified values of k"""
    maxk = max(topk)
    batch_size = target.size(0)

    _, pred = output.topk(maxk, 1, True, True)
    pred = pred.t()
    correct = pred.eq(target.view(1, -1).expand_as(pred))

    res = []
    for k in topk:
        correct_k = correct[:k].view(-1).float().sum(0)
        res.append(correct_k.mul_(100.0 / batch_size))
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: 恐らく、バッチサイズが異なるのでエラーが出ているように思います。`args.batch_size`では16と指定しているのに実際に入ってきたデータ`batch_size = target.size(0)`は256となっているのではないでしょうか。`parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size', default=16...`の場所を`default=256`にしてはいかがでしょうか

Comment: @nojule 様
回答いただきまして誠にありがとうございます。defaultの設定ではバッチサイズは256だったのですが、GPUの関係からか動かすことができませんでした。そこで、バッチサイズを小さくすることを考え16にしました。これに伴って他に変更する点はありますでしょうか。

Comment: GPUの関係で動かせないというのも少し気になりますが、その場合、target.size(0)が16に合わせることになるかと思います。ただtrain_loaderおよびtest_loaderを見るとtargetのバッチサイズはargs.batch_sizeとなっていそうに見えますね。output = model(input)や loss = criterion(output, target)のところで、input, output, targetのサイズを出力することはできますか？print(input.shape)などで…